# Azure Logic app get the file content from a multipart HTTP request

Tags: azure

I had a similar question recently I got some help and thought I had it working but the content was mulipart data and not the content of my file.  How can I save my file content only to the new file?

My problem is getting the right expression for File Content
[image]

the outputs of the first step is below.  I have my logfilename in the headers and then a body with the multipart data. There is a list of 2 parts, I am not sure I need the first one?  That looks like it might be on me.  The second part has the actual file content I want to save in the next step.
[edited] my dynamic content looks like this:
[image]
[image]
[image]

How do I access this field?  it is the third $content maybe but I tried all of them and often got a zero content file.  Similar understanding with $body where there are several of those.  I am sure I am missing something simple here.

[image]

I tried the above input and everything I could think of to access the correct $content but I still haven't hit on it.

Comment: What dynamic content are you presented with?

Comment: Thanks I can't easily respond with an image here so I updated the question to add the dynamic content screen clips

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `body` you provided in the HTTP request is an array, so if you want to write an expression that retrieves the relevant item (the second one) in the array, it would be ...

```
triggerBody()?['$multipart']?[1]?['body']?['$content']
```

The above is untested so see how it goes.

Comment: This is exactly the syntax I am missing!  but, the file is saved with the bas64 encoding intact so I just need to deal with that now.  Thanks!

Comment: Success!  I wrapped your snippet in a base64ToBinary and now it all works.  Thanks so much.  I struggled all day on this and you had the clue for me.

Comment: To help me understand, what syntax is this and where is it defined?   It doesn't look like js or python or anything I have used before

Comment: It's more JSON notation than anything.  This is about your best bet for getting more information but it's only marginally useful ... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference  Glad I could help anyway.